# Define Spring application properties default values on external library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In our company we have 100+ services built using Spring Boot. Most of these services share configuration values that allow us to configure how these applications register on Eureka, consume from Kafka and so on. This configuration is specified on the `application.yml` file in most of the services, and we'd like to avoid repeating these values, so we want to move this common configuration to a dependency that, when added to the classpath, will make that you no longer have to configure those values.

I achieved it by creating a new library which contains different `@Configuration` classes that configure the different beans with the right values. So now applications just need to add this library to the build.gradle file, and things are configured.

The problem is that, if one of the applications need to override any of the values for those beans, specifying the configuration in their `application.yml` file won't work, because I'm directly setting the right values to the bean.

For example, if my library declares this Bean

```
    @Bean
    @Profile("aws")
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigAWS(InetUtils inetUtils) {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigBean = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setDataCenterInfo(info);

        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setInstanceId(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.instanceId));
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localHostname));
        eurekaInstanceConfigBean.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localIpv4));

        return eurekaInstanceConfigBean;
    }
```

And someone specifies on the `application.yml` that they want a different hostname like

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: some-custom-value.example.com
```

It will be ignored: the configuration set in the bean will be used, not the local `application.yml` values.

Is there a way to achieve an order of precedence here where values specified on `application.yml` are more important than the values on the bean coming from the library? I'd like a precedence like:

*local application.yml > bean config in library > bean defaults coming from spring-boot/spring-cloud*

Comment: I am not sure that defining in a library properties which the value may change for multiple clients  be appropriate. You use Spring Cloud. Why not also use Spring Cloud Config ?

Comment: The value will be the same for 90% of the clients. It's not a value that may change often. I would rather do it without adding a new technology to the mix. In any case, would it be possible to achieve what I'm looking for with Spring Cloud Config?

Comment: Maybe define a different value (override.hostname or something) and in your library use that is it's set

Comment: I don't want to teach developers new properties :/

Comment: Why you don't check if there is property value before. If there is, you can get value form property, otherwise set hostname from AmazonInfo.